# Vector3D.Normalize() sometimes does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vector, 3d

I use `Vector3D.Normalize()` in C# to compare different vectors.
In some cases it did not work.
Therefore I made a simple sample just to show (not best coding).
How can I overcome this without using additional vectors like in `Test2`?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace Vecktor3D_Normalize_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vektor myVek = new Vektor();
            Vector3D myvector0 = new Vector3D(0.7, 0.5, 0.3);
            myVek.Test2(myvector0);
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2 " + myVek.myvector2);
            myVek.Test3(myvector0);
            Console.WriteLine("Test 3 " + myVek.myvector3);
            Console.WriteLine("Test 0 " + myvector0);
            myvector0.Normalize();
            Console.WriteLine("Test 1 " + myvector0);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Vektor
    {
        public Vector3D myvector2 { get; set; }
        public Vector3D myvector3 { get; set; }
        public void Test2(Vector3D Input)
        {
            Vector3D myvector4 = Input;
            myvector4.Normalize(); // myvector4 is normalized !!!!!!
            myvector2 = myvector4;
        }
        public void Test3(Vector3D Input)
        {
            myvector3 = Input;
            myvector3.Normalize(); // myvector3 is not normalized !!!!!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the program?

Comment: Could you give examples of cases where it did not work: what was the input, what was the expected output and what was the output ?

Comment: This programm is just to show the different behaviour. See // comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vector3D` is a `struct`, so by default it is passed by value.

This means `myvector3.Normalize` only normalizes a *copy* of `myvector3` obtained from its `get` function, not `myvector3` itself (or to be precise, the underlying hidden member variable which stores the value for the property `myvector3`). Hence you must be careful when replacing member variables with properties.

You could instead call `Normalize` on `Input`, for the same reason:

```
Input.Normalize();
myvector3 = Input;
```